Is there any difference between Wick time order and Dyson time order?
Reading A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-Body Problem by R. Mattuck, I am getting the feeling that I missed something subtle related to time order. When deriving the Dyson series for the evolution operator he defines a Dyson time order $\mathcal{T}_{\rm D}$ given by
$$\mathcal{T}_{\rm D}[B(t_1)A(t_2)]=\mathcal{T}[B(t_1)A(t_2)]=\left\{\begin{matrix} A(t_2)B(t_1)\quad\text{if }t_2>t_1\\ B(t_1)A(t_2)\quad\text{if }t_1>t_2\end{matrix}\right.$$
as this is done for the evolution operator where $A$ and $B$ are Hamiltonian-like he does not worry to define what happens with signs for fermions (even if later he does take it into account).
In a later chapter, he defines the Wick time order, that uses curly brackets
$$\mathcal{T}\{B(t_1)A(t_2)\}=\left\{\begin{matrix}\pm A(t_2)B(t_1)\quad\text{if }t_2>t_1\\  B(t_1)A(t_2)\quad\text{if }t_1>t_2\end{matrix}\right.$$
where the $\pm$ appears here because he is no longer talking about even number of creation-annihilation operators (so + for bosons, - for odd number of fermion swaps).
At some point in the book Mattuck says that the two time orders are mostly the same so he drops the D in $\mathcal{T}_D$. However in a same page, he sometimes uses both $\mathcal T[...]$ and $\mathcal T\{...\}$ as if there was a difference. In an appendix for example he writes the definition of the contraction
$$\overline{AB}= \mathcal{T}[AB]-\mathcal{N}[AB]$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the normal ordering, but then he writes an equality
$$\overline{AB}=\langle 0|\mathcal{T}\{AB\}|0\rangle$$
as if the two are different time orders.
explicitly stating that this time that it is the Wick time order.
As similar question is found here (no answers): Wick's time ordering operator
So when it is important to make a difference?

There is a difference, just by looking at definitions. However, due to the parity superselection, you usually consider an even number of fermionic operators, so both give the same result.

@TobiasFünke the definition for $\mathcal T$ does take into account the signs for odd number fermions, it is just explained later in the book. However I wonder why some books even care about the two, what is the difference? Also why keep a consistent notation?
